# Can't refer mesh size after using .BakeMesh() in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, mesh

I can't figure out how to refer to the size of a particular mesh.

The mesh is created through `.BakeMesh()`, then a box collider is added. Unfortunately the box collider has a scale of 1 by 1 by 1, regardless of how big the mesh I'm adding it to seems to be.

This doesn't match my understanding of how creating a box collider should work, so I've set up a Debug.Log that outputs the mesh size.

Here the plot thickens. The mesh's size just comes back at `0, 0, 0`. 
My attempts at getting the size of the object are as follows:

```
objectToMeasure.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size;

objectToMeasure.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.bounds.size

objectToMeasure.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh.bounds.size;
```

Assuming I'm referring to the size of the object in the correct way, this seems like it must be an issue created by baking the object. Do I need to wait a frame (via starting a coroutine) before trying to access the size of the object, or am I referring to the wrong component of the object, or is the BoxCollider setting it's size based on objectToMeasure's scale rather than it's size in the world?

I feel sure that
objectToMeasure.GetComponent().mesh.bounds.size;
should be right, since the script I use to bake to the mesh is: 
meshToBake.BakeMesh(meshToMeasure.GetComponent().sharedMesh);

I've been driving myself to the edge of sanity for 24 hours with this script not working, so advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried calling [RecalculateBounds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.RecalculateBounds.html) to ensure the bounds are up to date?

Comment: @DMGregory THANK YOU! That worked perfectly. Doing that would never have occurred to me.

Comment: If that worked for you, feel free to write it up as an answer. :) In future, remember to check through the docs for the types you're using to see if they have a method like this — it's a good way to spot possibilities that might not have crossed your mind.